# What do I do when a user suggests an edit to my answer and then posts a copy of my answer as their own?

Tags: discussion, answers, suggested-edits

A pretty old answer of mine (~5 years) had a bug. It said:

```
std::distance(start, end) <= chunkSize
```

when it should have said:

```
std::distance(start, end) >= chunkSize
```

Apparently nobody noticed until about 20 minutes ago, when a new user (member since today!) did the following in rapid succession:

- submitted an edit to my answer, correcting the erroneous comparison
- Like 20 seconds later, submitted a new answer to this question, which consists of just a block copy of the code in my answer with the erroneous comparison fixed (the new answer clearly cites that it is just fixing a bug with my answer)

I don't really know what to do in this situation. The new answer is now totally superfluous since I accepted the edit (effectively, it's become just a copy). Do I... flag it?

Comment: Giving the new user the benefit of the doubt, it seems like it was just a lack of understanding of how the edit system works and they were just trying to get a corrected version immediately visible on the page.

Comment: @TylerH Yeah certainly I don't mean to impugn the new user's motivations.

Comment: So...if he/she hadn't fixed it...you never would have noticed it, nor fixed your own answer?

Comment: You could just let the editor know you accepted their edit and they don't need to keep the duplicate answer. Flagging pushes them toward an answer ban, which seems a shame if this was just a misunderstanding.

Comment: It might also be a good idea to thank the new guy/girl for finding and reporting the bug.

Comment: @TylerH as a side note/clarification: if you have <2k rep and you edit a post, you can immediately see that post as if the edit had already been accepted. There is a box above the edited post that says something like "this edit is visible only to you until it's peer-reviewed".

Comment: @KevinG sure, but that doesn't mean the subject of the OP understood it or didn't feel like they shouldn't have to wait to have their contribution immediately visible (unfortunately).

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I suggest to mod flag it as

1. duplicate of an existing answer. This is standard clean-up practice if there are many answers.
2. <s>plagiarism. It doesn't reference your answer when copying it and as such, violates CC-BY-SA.</s> (It does reference it; couldn't easily check since the OP gave no link and this was unclear from explanation.)

Comment: _the new answer clearly cites that it is just fixing a bug with my answer_  I wouldnt call it plagiarism.. atleast not intentional

Comment: @SurajRao It's still not needed and can be deleted as such then.

Comment: It _is_ plagiarism, but of a form we can be lenient with, since this the new user probably just doesn't know how to use the site. At any rate, it should be handled by a moderator.

Comment: @Lundin Google defines plagiarism as "the practice of taking someone else's work or ideas and passing them off as one's own."  The user might've taken the OP's work, but didn't pass it off as his own, so I'd still not call that plagiarism.  Just a nitpick.

Answer (score -47):

> The new answer is now totally superfluous  ...

I'm not seeing a problem here, they reference your fix, and fixed it. If there is value add such as an explanation about the code, from the *other* answer don't flag it. If it is just an *exact* cut and paste, flag it.

Shouldn't Stack Overflow provide a correct answer regardless, even when/if duplicated?

---

As a user with many answers, I will review old answers that I have done and make edits to improve as they are upvoted after the initial written date.

⚠️ (IMHO) It seems a loss when someone (not directed at you) is out to answer to get the golden ring but then abandons the post; not keeping up with changes ....

Comment: OP has over 3,500 answers and this one is from five years ago.

Comment: So someone updated the answer because the OP has 3500 answers blocking?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by 'blocking'.

Comment: You stated that 'OP has 3500 answers', I didn't. If someone updated his answer and provided a new one that seems like a value add. If someone has 3500 answers, now one should edit his/her post? I don't like that logic.

Comment: @ΩmegaMan I don't think anybody suggests that when you get enough answers, you get "edit slaves" to do all the editing for you. More like this omission slipped through the cracks. Nobody brought attention to it, either. With so many answers, it's hard to constantly keep all of them up to date. Given the issue that was in the answer, it's not like there is anything *to* keep up to date - the answer from 5 years ago should work today, too. Unless you expect each contributer to regularly *re-answer* each question they've already answered a quick "looks OK" should be sufficient for those answers.

Comment: Nowhere in my answer above do I suggest that each answer has to be re-answered on some daily operation. All I suggest is that periodically one looks at an answers given as they are upvoted or downvoted which might catch an issue or change in technology.

Comment: To be clear: There was a **bug** in the answer. It was not an issue of updating it or not. You guys are developers (I assume): You know that it's impossible to be bug-free when writing so many lines of code (3500 answers must amount to a huge amount of code), and noticing bugs is **hard**. Give the OP a break.

Comment: @ΩmegaMan OK, *again* considering how trivial the bug was, I would reasonably expect that even if I wrote this, I'd look it over and say "Yep, the technology of doing a comparison haven't changed. This is good". In order to catch that this is a problem, you'd need to re-examine the whole question. Doing that is equivalent to re-answering it. A more reasonable expectation is to look over and see if there is anything to improve. If there is a bug you, nor anybody else, has noticed, then *by definition* this doesn't appear like something to change.